# Python flask how to return html as string without using render_template

Tags: python, flask

How to return html as string with a for loop inside without using render-template. I know how to do the for loop in a html file. my code here works in a separate html file:

```
<ul> 
    {% for i in city_names %}
    <li> {{ i.name }} </li>
    <% endfor %>
</ul>
```

but I just want to return the cities in the list city_names in a view function.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `render_template`?  That's how you render an HTML template with flask

Comment: because I will have next assignment to do render_template. This assignment only asks us to use one home.py file.

Comment: That's... A really silly requirement. Your teacher isn't helping you by introducing arbitrary restrictions. But you could always just manually build the HTML as a string.